# How to make "BlockInput On/Off" only block keyboard inputs not mouse

Tags: autohotkey

As the title says, I've had trouble finding a way for my script to only block keyboard inputs during my script. Is there a method that I've overlooked to do this? Here's my code for reference:

```
toggle = 0
*xbutton1::
{
  if GetKeyState("d", "P")
  {
    if GetKeyState("w", "P")
    {
        BlockInput On ;enabled
    Send, {d up}
    Send, {w up}
    Send, {a down}
    Send, {s down}
    Send, {K}
        BlockInput Off ;disabled when completed with the above actions ^ so no key inputs interfere
    Sleep, -1
    Send, {a up}
    Send, {s up}
    Send, {d down}
    Send, {w down}
    return
  }
```

Thanks! I'd appreciate any info or tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to only block keyboard input:

```
; Press F1 to block keyboard input for 10 seconds:

$F1::
    BlockKeyboard("On")
    Sleep, 10000
    BlockKeyboard("Off")
return

BlockKeyboard(state){
    Loop, 512
    {
        Key := Format("SC{:X}",A_Index)
        If (state = "On")
            Hotkey, *%Key%, KeyboardKey, On UseErrorLevel
        else
            Hotkey, *%Key%, KeyboardKey, Off UseErrorLevel
    }
    KeyboardKey:
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a modified AHKV2 version of it, thanks to the accepted answer:

```
func_BlockKeyboard(state){
    Loop 512
    {
        Key := Format("SC{:X}",A_Index)
        If (state = "On")
            Hotkey Key, do_nothing, "On UseErrorLevel"
        else
            Hotkey Key, do_nothing, "Off UseErrorLevel"
    }
    KeyboardKey:
    return
}
do_nothing(ThisHotkey)
{
    return
}
Insert::func_BlockKeyboard("On")
Insert & End::func_BlockKeyboard("Off")
```

Comment: Very late response but it's still relevant to me! Thanks will try later this week.